# Why does Google Apps Script gives me a "Cannot convert Array to String[][]." when I try to append a table to a document?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, runtime-error

I'm trying to read some data from a google sheet and write them in a table in a google doc, using Google Apps Script.

It seems to me that I have successfully created a two dimensional array in the script, and populated it with the data from the google spreadsheet.

I also created a document with a paragraph. However, when I try to append the table I get the error message "Cannot convert Array to String[][]".

Below you find a snapshot (from the debugger) of the table (called "griglia") I'm trying to write, using the instruction

```
var grg = body.appendTable(griglia);
```

[image: the table I created with the data from the spreadsheet (gives the error)]

I also tried with a "test" table, as in the example provided [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table).

[image: the test table I create (won't give an error)]

The test table won't give an error and appears in the document.

I cannot understand what is wrong with the first table (griglia).
The only thing that I notice is that the addresses in the second table are not increasing, while they are increasing in the first table. Is this relevant? Could I have made an error in creating the array?

I have a similar script, and it's working. It seems to me that I am creating the array and writing it in exactly the same way. In fact I copied most of the code from that script.

I did some research, but I could not find any clue.
I hope this is not too trivial, and that what I write is relevant.

Thanks

Comment: which line of code are giving you this error? was it from var grg = body.appendTable(griglia); ?

Comment: yes, sorry about that. As soon as the code gets there I get the error. No error with the "test" table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. 
The problem apparently was that I "allocated" 6 rows for the Array "griglia", but I actually "populated" only four of them (the ones shown in the figure above). The code for the allocation was the following

```
var griglia = new Array(6);  // <== here is the culprit
for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
 griglia[j] = new Array(numD+2);
}
griglia[0][0]="Domanda";
griglia[1][0]="Risposta";
griglia[2][0]="Motivazione";
griglia[3][0]="Totale";
for (c = 1; c<numD+1; c++){
 griglia[0][c]=c;
}  
griglia[0][numD+1]='tot';
```

As soon as I corrected the first allocation, changing it to

```
var griglia = new Array(4);
```

The error disappeared.

I feel really stupid. The debugger didn't help much, though, because it showed that griglia had 4 rows and not 6, of which two are empty.
Anyway, my bad.

I do not know whether I should delete my silly question and feel stupid privately or leave it in StackOverflow and feel stupid publicly, but perhaps help other people who might face the same error.